# Resize 1st Image with css

Tags: css

I am using this for auto resize in css

```
.maincont img {
    border: medium none;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
}
```

But it resize all the image in my post. I want to resize it only for my 1st image other image remained unchanged. Any solution ?

Comment: Show the HTML, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can try  `first-child` pseudo-class:

```
.maincont img:first-child {
    border: medium none;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
}
```